# How to get the AWS instance types to display

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish my website to AWS from visual studio, and am running into some difficulty.  I am supposed to select the instance type in the wizard, but for some reason the instance types are not populating.  Is there something that I haven't done on the AWS console?  I've already created a new t2.micro instance and generated a key pair.

Here is a screenshot of where I am stuck in the Visual Studio wizard:[image: Empty instance type box...]

Comment: Have you given your IAM user the proper permissions?

Comment: Yes, I think so...I've used it to create another micro instance before

Comment: Yes, Amazon EC2 full access and KMS and Elastic Beanstalk...

Comment: Have you shutdown VS and reopened it? Or rebooted the computer?

Comment: have shut down VS and reopened it. I'll try rebooting the computer..

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the keys you supplied when you initially created the project are incorrect. Make sure your keys in the config / app are still working as they should.